# Binding form - freemarker + Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, freemarker

I have a problem with binding my object in ftl form. 
Here is my controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveConfigProperties(@ModelAttribute("configCmdList") ConfigCmdList configCmdList, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    configurationDao.setConfigValues(configCmdList.getConfigurations());
    return "config";
}
```

and here is part of my ftl:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
            <@spring.bind "configCmdList" />                    
            <#list configCmdList.configurations as config>
                ${config.name}
            </#list>                            
            <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
        </form>
```

I have an access to my list of objects which I sent previous using GET method in my ftl, but my object list is null after sending object without modifications back to controller.
I tried to bind my configCmdList.configurations and also bind separately each element of that list in loop but without success.
What I'm missing?

VairalPatel web page is down and I remember that he wrote good example about freemarker form and spring mvc.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I think you need to loop through `${spring.status.expression}` or `${spring.status}`.  I'm not sure which.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I resolved an issue. I had to bind each list element and it parameters separately in loop using ${spring.status.expression} and ${spring.status.value}.
Here is my code:

```
<form action="" method="POST">  
            <#list configCmdList.configurations as config>    
                <@spring.bind path="configCmdList.configurations[${config_index}].id"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="${spring.status.expression}" value="${spring.status.value}" />

                <@spring.bind path="configCmdList.configurations[${config_index}].name"/>
                <input type="text" name="${spring.status.expression}" value="${spring.status.value}" />

                <@spring.bind path="configCmdList.configurations[${config_index}].value"/>
                <input type="text" name="${spring.status.expression}" value="${spring.status.value}" />
            </#list>                    
            <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
        </form>
```

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Would you please give me more details on how your Controller looks like (for GET and POST request)? Does it need to have modelAttribute as the form property (like: modelAttribute="configCmdList") ? I'm facing the same problem, but still not able to solve.

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to write [Caro's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28788694/2227743):

```
<form action="" method="POST">  
        <#list configCmdList.configurations as config>    
            <input type="hidden" name="configurations[${config_index}].id" value="${config.id}"/>

            <input type="text" name="configurations[${config_index}].name" value="${config.name}"/>

            <input type="text" name="configurations[${config_index}].value" value="${config.value}" />
        </#list>                    
        <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
    </form>
```